# Icons shows in chrome but not in other browsers

Tags: css, browser, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

I have successfully installed the LTEadmin2 template in yii2. Using google chrome, icons are working perfectly but not in the other browsers. What could be the cause of this error???

Here is the sample output in mozilla.(icons not showing)

[image]

And here is the output in chrome..

[image]

the code is here...

```
    <?= Html::a(' New', ['create', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-success  fa fa-plus']) ?>
    <?= Html::a(' Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary fa fa-pencil']) ?>
    <?= Html::a(' Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger fa fa-times',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

Comment: Please add HTML output.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, my guess is font-awesome is not being loaded correctly (maybe HTTP over HTTPS and Chrome is allowing it anyway). Please post HTML and/or link to live website where problem is happening

Comment: can you check browser debugger console to check warnings or errors related to fonts/images

Comment: Are you fetching the font from a CDN or from your own web server. If its your own web server then you need to ensure that the various font mime types (woff, woff2, eot, ttf, svg) are set up to be served correctly by your web server.

Comment: I am just in localhost...

arogachev and drew what do u mean by html output?? 

I think you are right @raunak. I get a 404 on the font awesome. I think I have just to correct this.

Comment: You are correct @RaunakKathuria..

Comment: try to add icon in normal html page. and check

Answer (score 0):

The LTEadmin2 template packages font awesome locally. I have encountered this issue before and it seems to be a bug rather than a coding issue and that is that some browsers seem to have an issue loading the font awesome web font files from the website and working with them. The workaround I have been able to find is to load the font awesome CSS file directly from the MAXCDN server using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`and that has seemed to solve the issue for me on all of my websites that I use LTEAdmin on.